# Partial Least Squares Discriminant Analysis

Tags: statistics, principal-components

Could anyone point me to detailed literature about "Partial Least Squares Discriminant Analysis"? Intuition, methodology and examples..

Thanks,

Comment: A simple google search gives you all you need. First 2 pdfs: http://enpub.fulton.asu.edu/cseml/06summer/pls_dis.pdf, http://users.stat.umn.edu/~sandy/courses/8801/articles/pls.pdf

Comment: Thanks, but I have already referred to those documents, but that was not really what I was looking for. I was hoping to get, beside the math formulation, some applications of PLS-DA to stock selection processes.

Comment: Let me get back to you with some references that include examples...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I liked the following introductions to Partial LS Discriminant Analysis:

[Partial Least Squares for Discrimination](http://enpub.fulton.asu.edu/cseml/06summer/pls_dis.pdf)

[A Beginner’s Guide to Partial Least Squares Analysis](http://users.stat.umn.edu/~sandy/courses/8801/articles/pls.pdf)

Here some references to examples:

[XLStat Spreadsheet (you may need to install the trial to run the full analysis in Excel)](http://www.xlstat.com/en/learning-center/tutorials/running-a-partial-least-square-pls-discriminant-analysis-with-xlstat-pls.html)

[R Package plsDA {DiscriMiner}](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/DiscriMiner/docs/plsDA)

[R Package Muma](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/muma/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the references already given by Matt I would recommend the following presentation which gives a good overview of the big picture, intuition and some mathematical background:

http://zoo.cs.yale.edu/classes/cs445/slides/Pfizer_Yale_Version.ppt‎

See esp. pages 71ff. and 206ff.

Comment: @Downvoter: It is customary here to give a reason for the downvote and perhaps a hint how to improve the answer - Thank you :-)